# Is there an easy way to draw on an image to change transparency?

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

Let me elaborate:

I'd like to load an image (ideally just using quartz) and set it to transparent. I would then like to be able to draw a line on that image and have the contents of that line under the image become visible. Is this possible? Would it involve masks of some sort, and if so, what sort of performance issues might I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You could either have a look at [`CGContextSetBlendMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) or maybe at [`CGContextClip`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html).

When using a blend mode you'd first draw your image transparently, then set the blend mode, then draw lines or other shapes. I don't really know much about the blend modes, but maybe somebody else can suggest a suitable one. Otherwise just try which one would work. You might be able to do this trial and error in some image manipulation program where you can set blend modes on layers...

When clipping, you'd first create a clipping path, set that with `CGContextClip`, and then draw your image.

I believe with the first approach you could have different alpha values, but with the second approach a pixel would be either visible or hidden.